# Declaring a function input parameter is equal to nil in Swift

Tags: swift

```
func taskWithMethod(URLString: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, queryParameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil){}
```

What is the difference between `parameters` and `queryParameters` in this function? Looks like `queryParameters` is being defined to nil, but I can still pass the `queryParameters` value to this function.

Comment: The `queryParameters` isn't "being defined to `nil`", but rather "will default to `nil`, if you don't provide it". In terms of how `taskWithMethod` uses these two dictionaries, you'd have to refer to that method's documentation and/or implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [Default Parameter Value (see section "Default Parameter Values")](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID160). If no value is passed in, it defaults to `nil`.

For example, this function can be called like so:

```
taskWithMethod(URLString: someString, parameters: dict1, queryParameters: dict2)
```

but it can also be called like so:

```
taskWithMethod(URLString: someString, parameters: dict1)
```

in which case `queryParameters` is set to its default value, `nil`.